# html form email php "From" formation

Tags: php, html, email

I am writing a html/php email form for a website. The php works fine, but on email side of the "From: " field of the emails header looks something like "Tomemxample@email.com" when I want it to look like "Tom, example@email.com". I am new to using php so I might be missing something syntax wise.

```
<?php 
    function spamcheck($field) {
        $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if(filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
    $email = test_input($_POST['email']);
    $subject = test_input($_POST['subject']);
    $message = test_input($_POST['message']);
    $to = "email goes here";
    $send = mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: " .$name .$email);
    if ($send) {
        header ("Location: http:// refreshes the page");
    } else {
        echo "The form could not be sent, please contact me at: email goes here";
    }

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the comma in between name and email :)

```
$send = mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name . ", " . $email);
```

Should be something like:

```
$send = mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name . "<" . $email . ">");
```

Check out

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

Put the email address between "<" and ">" as below :

```
   $send = mail($to, $subject, $message, "From:". $name ."<".$email.">". "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to RFC 5321 and 5322, what you are asking will form an invalid email address - commas or spaces are not permitted.

[RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321)

[RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)